# API for Days of The Year

Tags: api

I asked this question on Stack Overflow already, but it got closed. I hope, here is the right place to ask it.

So there is this great [website](https://www.daysoftheyear.com/), that tells me some interesting events of the current day. Searching for an API for it, I found [this page](https://www.daysoftheyear.com/api-data-services).

However I may be blind or whatever but I can't find any possibility to get the API endpoint.
And I am sure there is one, because [this website](https://www.programmableweb.com/api/days-year-rest-api) says, it has one.

I may be wrong with the terms, but what I want: I go to `www.daysoftheyear/some/thing.json` and get JSON data of today's events. Is this possible? If not, is there a public API for something like this?

I already contacted the site owners about this but it may take a long time to get an answer back.

Comment: That website is hard to read, it looks 1/2 broken. I would recommend https://www.timeanddate.com/services/api/ which requires a 3-month trial account, then a paid-for account. What exactly do you want to be able to do?

Comment: @spikey_richie , I am trying to make something similar to google's doodles. But in a discord bot, so that the bot tells "today is the day of Coloured Macaroni" for example. And best it would be some fun facts too, not some serious religious holidays

Comment: There's also https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/#/Feed/onThisDay

Comment: Still, not exactly what I want, the events are nothing funny. E.g "Same sexual marriage allowed in UK" or "Christian feast day", is not that interesting as "Day of Lemon Cake", that is at least nothing serious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I still did not manage to find some API endpoint for this, but I got what I wanted in another way: I used a similar website (https://nationaltoday.com/) which had oEmbed included in the homepage. Luckily, the oEmbed contains the events on that day.
I used the module `unfurled` for Node.js to get the oEmbed of that page as JSON, that I filter out and get the events.

Answer (score 1):

I just managed to get an API key for days of the year, and they granted me access via `curl -H 'X-Api-Key: [key]', 'https://www.daysoftheyear.com/api/v1/today'` but all my .json() answers (I'm using React) aren´t what I'm looking for.

They say, in the documentation, that you have to access with your key first, then access the endpoint, but I'm not sure how to deal with it, since I'm trying a lot of maners with some friends with good knowledge of javascript and we're not being able to access the data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).